# Is there a word for dying too much?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, poetic

I know that such a word would deny the meaning of death, but I was wondering if there was a word that enclosed this meaning, perhaps poetically.

**Context:**

Metaphorically speaking one could say one dies when an event happens to change your outlook on life immensely. So 'dying too much' could be, having such experiences too many times. The other context I though of when asking was on how there are some fictional characters/creatures, such as *a phoenix* or *The Doctor (Doctor Who)* who have the ability of living multiple lives, therefore dying many times, dying too much could be interpreted as dying many times in a short amount of time.

---

If anything, any word closely related to the phrase, without regard of it's context will be useful.

I did some reseach here, and on reddit, but I couldn't find anything close to it.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you mean.

Comment: As someone who has played many online video games (sometimes being the person that does a lot of the dying as well :P), I don't believe I have heard a special term for players that die repeatedly/too much.  That is the only area that quickly comes to mind where this word might apply.

Comment: For many people, dying even once is one time too many.

Comment: Some context would help. Do you mean one person physically dying? Maybe you're referring to a group of people? <br>
"The kudju peoples are dying too much from this blight, something must be done." <br>
"The red shirts on *Star Trek* are dying too much, someone is bound to notice this trend." For its "poetic" use, what do you want it to mean? A person is dying too quickly? A prototypical character dies too often? A character's death is overdone or maudlin? Or perhaps you're referring to ailment. For example, someone has cancer and they say, "I'm dying too much to care about this crap."

Comment: Dying too much poetically suggests there's something killing you "too much" poetically (perhaps killing you with kindness or other). I don't think there's a specific word for it, but images and metaphors that can  perfectly work in this kind of contexts sure abound.

Comment: Sorry about not giving out any context for it. Metaphorically speaking one could say one dies when an event happens to change your outlook on life immensively. So 'dying too much' could be, having such experiences too many times. The other context I though of when asking was on how there are some fictional characters/creatures, such as the phoenix or The Doctor (Doctor Who) who have the ability of living multiple lives, therefore dying many times, dying too much could be interpreted as dying many times in a short amount of time.

Comment: If anything, any word closely related to the phrase, without regard of it's context will be useful. Thanks!

Comment: A poetic/literary phrase is ***to die a thousand deaths***.

Comment: *His enlightenment was short lived.*

Comment: From Shakespeare's "Julius Caesar":  "Cowards die many times before their deaths; The valiant never taste of death but once."

Comment: This should have been a comment.

Comment: I like the above suggestion 'to die a thousand deaths'. I think the 'too much' part of the question is very subjective and means there will be different answers depending on the contenxt. If it's a video game and you can only die so many times before you are eliminated then died one time too many'. If you don't like the fact that the phoenix keeps coming to life: died one time too many for my taste. If it's a cat: it's 9 lives were up. If it's a nuclear power bombing a small nation in order to prove something then the nation is subjected to overkill. And so on.

Comment: From Seinfeld: "You can't overdie, you can't overdry".

Answer (score 2):

At least for your first context, I modestly put forth the new (as far as I know) phrase **epiphany junkie** .

Answer (score 1):

Stand up comics say they "cooked and bombed" on stage if they kept dying during their set.

"Dying" repeatedly means, of course, that their gags were failing to raise a laugh over and over again.

Can't think of anything else.

Comment: "The coward dies a thousand deaths; the hero only one."  or something like that. Not that this has anything to do with video games. What is the question in reference to???

Answer (score 1):

*Mortality* is the general word used to describe the rate of death, i.e. frequency of dying

"Event happens to change your outlook on life immensely" - the vocabulary used to describe such events is very subjective and far from the realm of my opening sentence. Personally I would call this "Ego Death" (I am not really the person I thought/pretended I was) or "Spiritual Awakening" (There is a whole new area of my existence that I just discovered) maybe even "Reality Check" (I'be been looking at this world wrongly).

Answer (score 0):

In video games you're a *noob*. In real life you've had a *humbling experience.*